# To what should the lat and long be converted to in order to be plotted correctly on google maps (Python)

Tags: python, google-maps

I am trying to plot on google maps the following latitudes and longitudes and according the data description they are expressed in terms of **decimal degrees.** which are not

```
0000000,0000000 ==> SKIP THAT
2095505, 5591222
2095363, 5531484
2094640, 5530295
2094491, 5529803
2053076, 5528274
2088596, 5547632
2088822, 5544034
2088787, 5547418
2089263, 5548341
2088282, 5545432
2119593, 5531504
2120369, 5528369
2120001, 5528532
2129025, 5548521
2133498, 5545644
2133041, 5548255
2131190, 5543177
2134787, 5548677
```

---

## example

**BOULEVARD MALESHERB, Paris, France** in the file has latitude = **4888990**, longitude = **0230392** When tried to look for it on [GPS Coordinate](https://www.gps-coordinates.org/) I got the following: 48.8800609 and 2.3135326000000305

## code source

The code source that I am using is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import gmplot
import csv

if __name__=="__main__":
    #set lattitudes and longitudes lists
    latitudes = []
    longitudes = []
    
    data = open("../data/test.csv")
    reader = csv.reader(data)
    #next(reader,None)
    for row in reader:
        lati = float(row[0])
        longi = float(row[1])
        print "%d,%d"%(lati,longi)
        latitudes.append(lati/1000000.0)
        longitudes.append(longi/1000000.0)
    
    gmap = gmplot.GoogleMapPlotter(latitudes[0], longitudes[0], 16)

    gmap.plot(latitudes, longitudes, 'cornflowerblue', edge_width=2)

    gmap.draw("mymap.html")
```

---

## Problem

The problem is that the points are being plotted correctly. I am ending in the bottom of the ocean lololololol. Whereas I should be somewhere in France.

How and what should the points be converted to in order to be plotted correctly?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your coordinates are expressed in units of 0.00001 decimal degrees. Likely they were scaled by a factor of 10000 so that they could be stored and manipulated as integers.

The solution is simply to divide the values by 10000 before passing them to Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the datum for your dataset, e.g. how the distances on axis X and Y are computed. <s>The original dataset is probably expressed in meters.</s> If your dataset is using [Web Mercator projection](https://epsg.io/3857), you have to convert meters in degrees accordingly. To convert between meters and degrees in the case of Web Mercator projection you need to implement [these functions for Pseudo-Mercator](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Mercator).
Also read [these answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/48949/epsg-3857-or-4326-for-googlemaps-openstreetmap-and-leaflet).

Comment: according to the documentation they are already expressed in **decimal degrees**. I think these A.holes aren't representing them correctly